# What does flag `pIOK` mean?

Tags: perl, xs, perlapi

When dumping perl SV with `Devel::Peek` I can see:

```
SV = IV(0x1c13168) at 0x1c13178
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (IOK,pIOK)
  IV = 2
```

But can not find the description what `pIOK` mean.

I tried to look it at `Devel::Peek`, `perlapi` , `perlguts`, `perlxs` ...
In sources I found that:

```
{SVp_IOK, "pIOK,"}
```

But still can not find what `SVp_IOK` is. What is it?

**UPD**
I found [this document](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RURBAN/illguts-0.49/index.html). It shed the light a bit what flags mean and where they are situated. (beware this DOC is outdated a bit)

[image]

> This flag indicates that the object has a valid non-public IVX field value. It can only be set for value type SvIV or subtypes of it.

**UPD**

[Why private and public flags are differ](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html#What's-Really-Stored-in-an-SV?)

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: If I understand right, when SV has string and this string contain integer value the `SVp_IOK` will be true and `SV_IOK` will be false, will not?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: Do you know the case when only one of two flags is used?

Comment: @Gerhard: This is mostly wrong, and I don't know what you mean you mean by the *lower* flags.

Comment: @Borodin  lower case I mean. will delete and repost as I cannot edit the comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pIOK` is how `Devel::Peek` represents the bit corresponding to bit mask `SVp_IOK`. The `p` indicates a "private" flag, and it forms a pair with "public" flag `IOK` (bit mask `SVf_IOK`)

The exact meaning of the private flags has changed across perl versions, but in general terms they mean that the `IV` (or `NV` or `PV`) field of the `SV` is "inaccurate" in some way

The most common situation where `pIOK` is set on its own (`pIOK` is always set if `IOK` is set) is where a `PV` has been converted to a numeric `NV` value. The `NV` and `IV` fields are both populated, but if the `IV` value isn't an accurate representation of the number (i.e. it has been truncated) then `pIOK` is set but `IOK` is cleared

This code shows a way to reach that state. Variable `$pi_str` is set to a *string* value for π and it is converted to a floating-point value by adding 0.0 and storing it into `$pi_num`. `Devel::Peek` now shows that `NOK/pNOK` and `POK/pPOK` are *set*, but only `pIOK` while `IOK` remains clear. Looking at the `IV` value we can see why: it is set to 3, which is the cached value of `int $pi_str` in case we need it again, but it is *not* an accurate representation of the string `"3.14159"` in integer form

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Devel::Peek 'Dump';

my $pi_str = "3.14159";

my $pi_num = $pi_str + 0.0;

Dump $pi_str;
```

#### output

```
SV = PVNV(0x28fba68) at 0x3f30d30
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (NOK,POK,IsCOW,pIOK,pNOK,pPOK)
  IV = 3
  NV = 3.14159
  PV = 0x3fb7ab8 "3.14159"\0
  CUR = 7
  LEN = 10
  COW_REFCNT = 1
```

Perl v5.16 and before used to use the flag to indicate "magic" variables (such as *tied* values) because the value in the `IV` field could not be used directly. That was changed in v5.18 and later, and magic values now use `pIOK` in the same way as any other value

Comment: the `SVp_IOK` mask has only *one* bit set: `0x00001000`. What do you mean: "It forms a pair?"

Comment: `that POK/pPOK and POK/pPOK are set`: Do you mean `that POK and pPOK are set`. If so, please fix

Comment: @EugenKonkov: I mean that `IOK` and `pIOK` are a pair. I have already said that *"`pIOK` is always set if `IOK` is set"* and I don't know how to write it any more clearly.

Comment: @Eugen: If you are so unfamiliar with perl internals then you should rely on the `SvIOK(SV*)` macro. It will suffice except for advanced XS code (which is already an advanced technique).